Read from jfrog private url in api swagger in backstage
I have to read my openapi specs from my organization jfrog instance and the url looks like, https://mycompany.jfrog.io/artifactory/project-1/api-specs/openapi.yaml However in order to read this url,jfrog authentication needs to be in place.
This is my catalog-info.yaml file
apiVersion: backstage.io/v1alpha1
kind: API
metadata:
  name: petstore
spec:
  type: openapi
  definition:
    $text: https://mycompany.jfrog.io/artifactory/project-1/api-specs/openapi.yaml

